# routes in exported router not available in app

Tags: express, routes

I'm trying to export a router 'Accounts' to use in my app. The 'Accounts' router has the paths '/login' (POST), '/register'(POST), 'login' (GET), and '/logout' (POST). In my index app I am using the router with the path '/account'. So the paths should be:

```
/account/login (POST)
/account/login (GET)
/account/register(POST)
/account/logout (GET)
```

But when I call these paths they aren't found by the app:

[image]

How do I get the paths in the 'accounts.js' router to work in the 'index.js' app?

My file structure is like this:

[image]

my account.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const Account = require('../models/Account');
const Branch = require('../models/Branch')
const router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});


const registerAccount = (req, res, next) => {
     //register the account
};

const createUser  = (req,res) => {
     //create a user in another db
}


router.post('/register',
    [registerAccount, createUser]);



router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.json(user);
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: 'account/login' }));

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

});

module.exports=router;
```

and my index.js looks like this:

```
// index.js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var jwt = require("jwt-simple");
var auth = require("../auth/auth.js")();
var users = require("./users.js");
var cfg = require("../config.js");
const accountController = require('./account');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(auth.initialize());
app.use('/account',accountController);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        status: "My API is alive!"
    });
});


app.post("/token", function(req, res) {
    //some token stuff that doesn't matter here
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you don't pass an array to a `router.post()`, so change this:

```
router.post('/register', [registerAccount, createUser]);
```

to this:

```
router.post('/register', registerAccount, createUser);
```

And make sure that `registerAccount` calls `next()` when it's done and wants `createUser()` to get called.

In [the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method), for this syntax:

```
app.post(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

the brackets in `[, callback]` mean that parameter is optional.  The brackets are not supposed to be used.